# How to truncate lines by default

Tags: line-truncation

Almost every text editor is able to truncate lines by default, but in Emacs I'm still using the cumbersome `M-x toggle-truncate-lines` in every buffer with long lines.  Unfortunately, buffers with long lines are very common, so one has to do `M-x toggle-truncate-lines` constantly.

Solutions currently posted on StackOverflow do not work (e.g., [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577614/emacs-truncate-lines-in-all-buffers)):

- `(setq-default truncate-lines t)` in `init.el` does not have any effect.
- `(custom-set-variables '(truncate-lines t))` in `init.el` does not have any effect.
- `(global-set-key "\C-x\ w" 'toggle-truncate-lines)` does not really solve the problem.

I must be overlooking something here; what's the actual setting for truncating long lines by default?

Comment: The answer given so far is correct, but solves it the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### `truncate-lines` possibly overridden

The built-in help for `truncate-lines` mention that it is overridden by the variable `truncate-partial-width-windows`. You might want to check if it is set by using `<C-h> v` and typing `truncate-partial-width-windows`.

#### Relevant portion of built-in help for `truncate-lines`

```
...
Note that this is overridden by the variable
`truncate-partial-width-windows' if that variable is non-nil
and this buffer is not full-frame width.
...
```

Comment: (global-visual-line-mode) works as expected. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950340/how-do-you-activate-line-wrapping-in-emacs/950406#950406

Comment: @JiacaiLiu, it does, if you expect something else than _scrolling_, which is what the OP is actually after (referring to the default behavior of "almost every text editor" :) ). "Truncating lines" and its relation to horizontal scrolling seems to be yet another arcane emacs (mis)feature to turn a common and trivial thing into something properly confusing and frustrating. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the nil value of `truncate-lines`.

If you want the line to wrap around, producing this:

[image: emacs wrapping]

Then you want `(setq truncate-lines nil)`.

(Based on your "almost every editor" comment, this was probably your desired behaviour. It's confusing in Emacs because `M-x toggle-truncate-lines` toggles the state, and doesn't clarify which state is considered 'truncated'.)

Comment: I honestly can't imagine confusion over which state is "truncated".